# R: which.min seems not work in my data frame

Tags: r

I'm sorry about this newbie question.
I have a data frame like

```
l_tab$dis2_num$perc
  Var1        dis       pol        dif
1    1 0.79867550 0.2198391 0.57883635
2    2 0.14569536 0.1983914 0.05269606
3    3 0.05562914 0.5817694 0.52614030
```

Where I would like to find the min value of dif.
I have try this:

```
> min(l_tab$dis2_num$perc["dif"])
>[1] 0.05269606
```

And that's correct, but i would like to recover also the row (in this case 2)

Searching for this stuff, i have try this:

[Sorting and finding values in other data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7345643/sorting-and-finding-values-in-other-data-frames)

that recommends the function which.min().

The problem arise when i try to apply this to my data

```
> which.min(l_tab$dis2_num$perc["dif"])
Erreur dans which.min(l_tab$dis2_num$perc["dif"]) : 
  the objet (list) can't be converted to type 'double'

> typeof(l_tab$dis2_num$perc)
[1] "list"
```

I don't understand why my data frame has become a list.

Also I have tried this

```
> r = as.data.frame(r)
> r

  Var1        dis       pol        dif
1    1 0.79867550 0.2198391 0.57883635
2    2 0.14569536 0.1983914 0.05269606
3    3 0.05562914 0.5817694 0.52614030

> typeof(r)
[1] "list"
```

without any result...

Comment: It would be more insightful to have asked why did "[" not deliver an atomic vector from inside a list. Next time look at `str( l_tab$dis2_num$perc["dif"] )`

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't have enough level even to know what is an atomic vector...

Comment: Two kind of vectors in R: lists and atomic.

Answer (score 5):

A data.frame is a list and `[` returns a sub-list. Instead, to extract the list item (the vector), you can do:

```
 which.min(l_tab$dis2_num$perc[["dif"]])
```

or

```
 which.min(l_tab$dis2_num$perc$dif)
```